# Аналог FSR на JS, масштабирование изображение с меньшими потерями JS

Tags: javascript, нейронные-сети, масштабирование

Есть ли способ масштабировать изображение в браузере клиентов с меньшими потерями, подобно технологиям масштабирования изображений видеоигр, вроде FSR?

Есть приложение, содержащее большое количество фото. Заранее известно, что у клиентов во время использования приложения будет медленный интернет. Сейчас изображения загружаются размером 350px по ширине и в качестве 70% (jpg). Есть ли способ масштабирования изображения, например, до 700px по ширине с меньшими потерями в качестве, чем это происходит стандартными алгоритмами браузеров? Может есть готовая нейронная сеть небольшого размера, работающая на JS для этих целей или библиотека?

Comment: Вангую, что данное решение будет настолько затратным в плане производительности, что куда проще  взять ссылку на изображение, отправить аякс куда-то на апи инструмента по нужной вам процедуре, получить ответ и вставить обратно.